# Ionic + Android - Firebase Fails to Initialize

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run my Ionic app on my Android device like so

```
ionic run android
```

However, when it comes time to initialize my Firebase database, the app comes to a halt (so far I don't see any error messages, I just get a blank screen)

I know it is Firebase that is preventing the app from running as the second `alert()` below never gets called (I've also ran the app fine before introducing Firebase)

```
alert('before init');  // shows up on the device
/** Firebase Initialization **/
var config = {
  apiKey: "myApiKey",
  authDomain: "myApp-43426.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myApp-43426.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "myApp-43426.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "3435303453"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
alert('after init'); // never called
```

As an FYI, I have **anonymous** enabled in my Firebase Authentication settings

Has anyone had a similar experience with this? How can I ensure Firebase will initialize on any/all Android (and iOS) devices?

Thanks much!

Comment: does it run/initialize correctly in the browser?

Comment: @AaronSaunders It does!

Comment: i suggest you remote debug and see what error is getting generated https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/